# Triggering an event on one subform based on a change in another subform

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a main form with two subforms. The first subform (subformList) displays a list of employees and a second subform(subformDetails) provides the details for that employee.

I use the practice of having a control field in the main form hving the value of the chosen employee in the subformList subform and having the master/child link of the employee details subform based on this value.

Up to this pointe everything works great. I choose an employee is one subform and the other subform displays the new details.

The problem I have is that I need a of one of the fields in the subformDetails form to execute after the details change from clicking another employee in the subformList subform. If I code a requery of the control field in question in the subformDetails field, it simply requeries with the old value (the control is a listbox with a query as a record source. As expected I can click on the same employee in the subformList subform a second time and the correct details are displayed in the control field in question.

So the question that I have is: Is there a way to rigger an event AFTER the forms have updated each other.

Note that I thought I could simply have an event one of the subformDetails controls so when the other subform forms forces a change then there would be a trigger to perform the requery I need. However it seems events are based on direct changes and not coded changes from other forms.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst writing the question I thought that maybe what I should do is manually force the subformDetails to be refreshed before executing the requery for the control (listbox) and this worked.

So just to summarise

When I click on an employee in the employee list subform I have an onclick event that would run a requery on a listbox in the employee details subform. Unfortunately this requery uses a control box in the employee details subform that does not get updated until sometime after the onclick event (the relationship between the two forms is established with the link master/child and a hidden field in the main form.

The fix is to requery the employee details subform before I run the requery for the listbox. This is because click on the employee in the list changes to record source row and refresh the form makes sure the control has that new value before the listbox requery is executed.

I still don't know what triggers the form change between the two subforms in the first place. It must be performed implicitely.

Comment: you should use the edit function and edit your original post not answering your own question that is not an answer ;)

Comment: WHat do you mean by not an answer, the answer is to requery the employee details subform before requery the listbox. I guess answering my own question that I find a solution to is not what should be done on this site which is troubling because I have just answered another of my own questions whilst trying a few things. As suggested I will include the answer in the comments rather than marking it as answered.